# how can I use String.IndexOf method to find the correct value?

Tags: c#, regex, string, winforms, indexof

I want to make my sentence like below, but how can I use String.IndexOf method to find the correct value of MINVALUE to make start with value change in sentence with given conditions?

***sentence***

> CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 55  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE

***result***

> CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 8  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE

***Conditions***

1. if MINVALUE has plus value (8) than make start with value same as
   MINVALUE (8)...
2. if MINVALUE has minus (-8) value than make start with value same as MAXVALUE (999)

***My Code***

```
var startvalue = 0;
if(MINVALUE > 0)
{
    startvalue = MINVALUE;
}
Else if(MINVALUE < 0)
{
    startvalue = MAXVALUE;
}
var result = String.Format(@"CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST_SEQUENCE"" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH {0}  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE",startvalue)
```

Comment: does c# has `indexOf` method on the String class?

Comment: I don't believe you need to escape your " when using @.  You use @ so you don't need to do that.

Comment: @ethorn10 it is not a homework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you;

```
string sentence = @"CREATE SEQUENCE 'MY_TEST_SEQUENCE' MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 55 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE";
string pattern = @".*\s+MINVALUE[ ]*(?<MinValue>[-?\d]*)[ ]*MAXVALUE[ ]*(?<MaxValue>[\d]*)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = rgx.Match(sentence);
Group gp1 = match.Groups[1];//-8 or 8 (both valid).
Group gp2 = match.Groups[2];//Value after MAXVALUE.
if (gp1.Value.StartsWith("-") == false)//No minus sign,that must be a positive value.
{
  string s2 = string.Format(@"CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST_SEQUENCE"" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999  INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH {0} CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE", gp1.Value);
  MessageBox.Show(s2);
}

else if (gp1.Value.StartsWith("-") == true)//No need for further checking, a value with - will always be smaller.
{
  string s2 = string.Format(@"CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST_SEQUENCE"" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH {0} CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE", gp2.Value);
  MessageBox.Show(s2);
}
```

Comment: can you help me on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705075/i-want-to-make-my-code-dynamically-depends-on-the-sentences-that-comes-from-orac

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a regular expression with capture groups would be a better fit than trying to break the string into pieces.

```
var regex = new Regex(@".*\s+MINVALUE\s+(-?\d*)\s+MAXVALUE\s+(-?\d*)\s+.*");
var sentence = @"CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST_SEQUENCE"" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 55 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE";

var match = regex.Match(sentence);

if (match.Groups.Count != 3)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("input string not in expected format");
}

var minValue = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
var maxValue = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

var result = string.Format(@"CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST_SEQUENCE"" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH {0}  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE", minValue < 0 ? maxValue : minValue);
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.ApplicationException' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @user2760129 - forgot to include `new`, fixed

Comment: @user2760129 - I hadn't tested it and neglected the fact that the entire string would be one of the match groups.  I've fixed it now.  I hope this isn't for a class. If it is, you'd better do some quick study on regular expressions in case your prof wants to know how you came up with this solve. :)