# how can I connect to database

Tags: database-connection

I use this but I can't connect DataBase

```
  conn1.Open();
    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand);
```

Comment: Don't know how to help you, but I can provide this little bit of advice: Change the title of your question. I'm pretty sure most everyone here modifies their code from time to time.

Comment: @Steve , Thanks for advice! will do that

Comment: @user2760129 No problem,to make it dynamic instead,define `sentence` as a global field,and where ever in your code you are retrieving strings from your database,make sure to assign each string to `sentence`,like this `sentence=string 1;`where `string1` is the string you just extracted.  If you need more explanation just ask without hesitation.

Comment: @AviralSingh, Thanks for the reply, Can you modify the code and show me there please?

Comment: @AviralSingh,  I can assigned each sentence but when trying to print the result with string.Format method. How would I put my sentence...? Because it has string.Format(Sentence....startwith{0}........,gp1.value)

Comment: @user2760129 Please give me some time to do some tests,i will post the solution as soon as i get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it dynamic use this;

```
    string sentence = "";
    string formatprototype = "";//This will hold the string to be formatted.
    string output="";

    public void SearchString()
    {
        string pattern = @".*[ ]+?[\""]{1}(?<String>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[\""]{1}[ ]+?MINVALUE[ ]*(?<MinValue>[-?\d]*)[ ]*MAXVALUE[ ]*(?<MaxValue>[\d]*)[ ]+?[INCREMENT]*[ ]+?[BY]*[ ]+?(?<IncrementBy>[\d]*)[ ]+?[START]*[ ]+?[WITH]*[ ]+?(?<StartWith>[\d]*)[ ]+?[CACHE]*[ ]+?(?<Cache>[\d]*)\s+?";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        Match match = regex.Match(sentence);
        Group @string = match.Groups[1];
        Group minvalue = match.Groups[2];
        Group maxvalue = match.Groups[3];
        Group incrementby = match.Groups[4];
        Group startswith = match.Groups[5];
        Group cache = match.Groups[6];
        formatprototype = @"CREATE SEQUENCE ""{0}"" MINVALUE {1} MAXVALUE {2} INCREMENT BY {3} START WITH {4} CACHE {5} NOORDER NOCYCLE";
        if (minvalue.Value.StartsWith("-"))
        {
            output = string.Format(formatprototype, @string, minvalue, maxvalue, incrementby, maxvalue, cache);
        }
        else if (!minvalue.Value.StartsWith("-"))
        {
            output = string.Format(formatprototype, @string, minvalue, maxvalue, incrementby, minvalue, cache);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(output);
    }
```

Assume that `SearchString()` is the function in which you are doing this stuff.And make sure to assign each string that is extracted from database,to `sentence`.Try it and reply if it worked or not.

Comment: if you check my "Inside my database I have 3 sequences that needs to be change..." titled. My each sentence is changing, and how can I replace each sentence inside string.Format method to make it work?

Comment: didn't work :( For each sentence my string is changing... and It doesnt work with the new string... because still same string value inside the string.Format method

Comment: No didnt work, I am getting:   CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 8 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

Comment: I suppose to get CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 999 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE;  for my first sentence

Comment: @user2760129 I don't know how you are testing it, i have tested it with each of the strings you mentioned and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi Aviral, My sentences are updated please check it out.Thanks

Comment: @user2760129 See the updated answer,i have tested it with all three strings and it works perfectly.

Comment: Almost there, Only error is getting MAXVALUE 999, but they are different too.

Comment: when the sentence has - minus it suppose to get MAXVALUE, but it gets MINVALUE as minus and assigned to start with value.For example, it makes my first sentence like this:  CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH -8 CACHE 50 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

Comment: But it suppose to get make it like:CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 999 CACHE 50 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

Comment: @user2760129 Sorry for that,I forgot to change the if-else statements when I changed the groups.I've updated it.

Comment: PLUS valued sentence has no error, but Now I am getting error on if sentence has MINUS value:CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 999 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 999 CACHE 50 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

Comment: @user2760129 So what are you getting if you set `sentence=CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST"" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 5780 INCREMENT BY 9 START WITH 11  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE` ?

Comment: if my sentence is this sentence=CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST"" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 5780 INCREMENT BY 9 START WITH 11 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE.....I am getting  CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST"" MINVALUE 5780  MAXVALUE 5780 INCREMENT BY 9 START WITH 5780  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE

Comment: I suppose to get sentence=CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST"" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 5780 INCREMENT BY 9 START WITH 5780 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE

Comment: ERROR:  output doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: After added string output="";  Now getting this: CREATE SEQUENCE "" MINVALUE MAXVALUE INCREMENT BY  START WITH CACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE

Comment: @user2760129 I don't have enough fingers to point what wrong happens with you code,the answer I've posted now is 100% working for each string you mentioned.As I was writing the comment I again tried the method and it gave what was expected.It would be better if you post the code which extracts strings from database,maybe there might be something that is causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

for connect to Oracle from application

```
     string command =  "Enter your command";  
        OracleConnection orclecon;
             orclecon = new OracleConnection(connection);
  orclecon.Open();
```

use this for select commands:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 using (OracleDataAdapter Oda = new OracleDataAdapter(command, orclecon))
                {
                    Oda.Fill(ds);
                }
```

and use this for insert/update/delete commands:

```
//used for Oracle command (insert,update,delete) if number of rows that affected >0 return true else return false

using (OracleCommand orclcommand = new OracleCommand(command, orclecon))
                        {
                            int n = orclcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            if (n > 0)
                                return true;
                            else
                                return false;
                    }
    orclecon.Close();
```